# LaTeX: How to make list of listings look like list of figures?

Tags: latex

I have a list of figures and a list of listings in LaTeX. I created both with `\listoffigures` and `\lstlistoflistings`. However, they are displayed differently (see pictures (they are in German)). How can I make the lol look like the lof? So I mean the lol in bold and without an extra heading above the line above.

[list of listings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tY529.png)

[list of figures](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ReOTP.png)

Comment: Actually, I can't see any difference in the list itself. What seems to be different is the page style and the style of the title. Since `\lstlistoflistings` is not part of any standard class, I guess you use a package for the listings. Have a look in the package's manual how it influences page style and if it uses standard title styles.

Comment: Please make a [mre]